# Subtracting array values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am getting data from a MySQL database using an array (via PHP).

I was wondering, is it okay to subtract array values, like this (on line 7):

```
$num = 30;

$result1 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table1');
$result2 = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table2');

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1) && $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $sub = $row1['number'] - $row2['number'];
    if($sub<=$num) {
        echo $row1['person'];
}
```

I'm actually not getting any results back (just blank). So I was wondering if that line or any parts of my code is logically correct?

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: You can do it in query only.

Comment: Your if-clause is open but not closed.

Comment: Use of SQL JOIN might be a better option

Comment: @st2erw2od, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @iamkdev, thanks for the suggestion, but how would I go about writing that in my current code?

Comment: @Sougata, okay I see. Just like how iamkdev suggested?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, thanks for posting those links., thanks for posting those links.

Comment: There has to be a common column in both the table (reference key or foreign key - I assumed [id - table1_id] )

`SELECT number.table1 as n1, number.table2 as n2, colName.tableName FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON id.table1 = table1_id.table2`

Comment: @iamkdev, yes there is a common column between them. Would I put that select statement within the WHILE fuction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$num = 30;

$result = mysql_query('SELECT number.table1 as n1, number.table2 as n2, colName.tableName FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON id.table1 = table1_id.table2');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $sub = $row['n1'] - $row['n2'];
  if($sub<=$num) {
    echo $row['person'];
  }
}
```